# Create a Image Database with shortcuts containing relative paths to image files in Windows

Tags: windows, relative-path

So I am creating a image database. I use one folder called "all" to store all image files inside, and other nested folders as categories, storing the shortcuts to the image files.

For example, Animals, Environment are 2 big categories, with Cats, Dogs and Architecture, Landscapes as sub-categories. The structure would look something like this:

```
Pictures\all           <- storing every image files
Pictures\Animals
Pictures\Animals\Cats  <- storing shortcuts to image files
Pictures\Animals\Dogs
Pictures\Environment
Pictures\Environment\Architecture
Pictures\Environment\Landscapes
```

The reason for this structure is as some pictures fit in multiple categories, like a photo with a dog laying in front of a house, would fit in both the Dogs and Architecture categories. Using shortcuts instead of copying files into multiple folders helps to reduce the capacity used.

I put them into my mobile hard drive for easy access, but there is a problem.

The problem is when I change computer, the drive letter will change as well. One work around is to change the drive to a fixed one, e.g. M:\, for the computers that I have the right to do so. But sometimes I don't own the computer I am using, e.g. a friend's computer or computer at work, and I can't change it.

Is there a way to create shortcuts with relative paths in this case? If not, is there another way to store the image files?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a way to do that.

Using [My Photo Index](http://portableapps.com/node/20908) with PortableApps would be a solution.

---

Edit: The program has some bugs. It turns out it is not fully capable to do what I want to do.